# Mouse click is not working for WPF ComboBox Cotrol, but i can navigate items with keyboard

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

This is the code I have to place a combobox, but it don't work with mouse. It only work with        keyboard..

```
<ComboBox 
   FontSize="20" Focusable="True" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
   Margin="0,140,250,0"
   VerticalAlignment="Top"
   Width="220"
   Loaded="ModeComboBox_Loaded"
   SelectionChanged="ModeComboBox_SelectionChanged">
   <ComboBox.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush  x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightBlue"/>
   </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

I think the problem is with focus?? but not sure..

Comment: I just tried your code and it all works just fine with a mouse... of course, you didn't really describe your problem, so unless you clearly explain your problem, we can't help you.

Comment: Take out the Loaded and SelectionChanged.  Bet you are breaking it in one of those.

Answer (score 0):

Elements that inherit from ButtonBase have a click event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.aspx

ComboBox doesn't inherit from ButtonBase, therefore it doesn't have a Click event.

There are a OnMouseUp and OnMouseDown events that you can try using instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.aspx

With regards to the actual question, I'm assuming that the problem is that SelectionChanged doesn't fire when you change selection with a mouse?